# I want to add an image to the slideshow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap template, but cannot get the slideshow working properly as demonstrated here - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I want to add my own image instead of the URL image that is already there.

Comment: Please try to recreate your problem, minimally, in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It is difficult to help when there is no concrete example to work on.

Comment: I just need to know how to replace the "url(http image) with my own image located in a folder :( Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you're using an old, unsuppported version of bootstrap? Or are you stuck with what your template author supplied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working locally you can change that URL to wherever you are saving your image. For example, I like to put my images in a folder called "img", so my code might look like this:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/my-image-here.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: Ah! Perfect, damn thats really simply when you know ;) I thought I had to change URL to something :S Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Check it off as the accepted answer when you're done.